# Java Convert FilePart to byte[] in Springboot using Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor

I want to get the byte content of the File.
Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/files")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<UserFilesResponse> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") FilePart file) {

// I want to get the bytes[] content of my file. How can I do it please ??
}
```

Comment: You can use `content` for that? However what do you want to do with the `byte[]`? If to store it somewhere use one of the `transferTo` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I want the byte[] because I save to Google Cloud Storage and I do it this way: 
storage.create(blobInfo, <byte[]>);
So I can get the blobinfo, I need to have the byte[] to store the Data to GCloud Storage. 
Thanks

Comment: You should use the `content` then and read the `DataBuffer`.

Answer (score 4):

As M. Deinum mentioned, you should use `content`

I would also recommend https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.html#join-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-

```
DataBufferUtils.join(filePart.content())
    .map(dataBuffer -> dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().array())
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to convert it to a byte array and then storing it in the database?

Comment: well, the question was about getting bytes from FilePart. The decision of storing byte array in DB or FS or any cloud should depend on your business-process. It's a topic for a separate question :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert filepart to Byte Array

```
private byte[] convertFilePartToByteArray(FilePart file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.filename());
        file.transferTo(convFile);
        return Files.readAllBytes(convFile.toPath());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<UserFilesResponse> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {

byte[] fileBytes = file.getBytes();

//rest of code
}
```

I would suggest to use multipart file instead of just file part, this will enable you to call the getBytes() method and get the byte array.